# How is "this" defined in a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Assume a react component with _onChange function like this

```
_onChange:function () { this.setState({})};
```

This _onChange function is passed to store as a listener for change event.
So when _onChange is called, it is actually called by store, store as an eventEmitter actaully use code like

```
 handler.call(this);
```

to call the handler.Thus this in _onChange function should be the store. However, it works out this in _onChange is the component.
Therefore, I wonder how does flux manage to set "this" keyword of _onChange to the actual component when the function is called ?

Comment: Are you asking how something works or a bug you're having in your code? You can easily store a reference of `this` and use that when operating inside another function ... `var self = this; someFunc(self.setState...);`

Comment: I am asking something that works but I think is a bug. What I try to ask is this in _onChange when it is called should be the store but not component.

Answer (score 0):

Because `_onChange` is being defined in the component and not the store, `this` is relative to the component instance. When the store fires the callback, it's doing so in the context of your component, so `this` is valid.

This behavior is different depending on if `"use strict"` is declared.

> In strict mode, the value of this remains at whatever it's set to when entering the execution context.

Check out the [docs on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: it is because react.createClass does the auto binding on the method automatically.